# Bash remove exact matching variables and search for string ignoring case

Tags: bash

**First Query:**

i have a text file username.txt contains

```
user1
user2
user3
```

My Bash file is as follows > test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# REMOVE user which donot have any COMBLIMIT
num=0
cat /tmp/username.txt | while read users
do
num=$[$num+1]
USERID=`echo $users | awk '{print $1}'`
SRVID=`mysql -uxxx -pxxx -e "use radius; SELECT srvid FROM radius.rm_users WHERE rm_users.username = '$USERID';" |awk 'FNR == 2 {print $1}'`
COMBLIMITCHECK=`mysql -uxxx -pxxx -e "use radius; SELECT limitcomb FROM rm_services WHERE srvid = '$SRVID';" |awk 'FNR == 2 {print $1}'`
if [[ $COMBLIMITCHECK -eq "1" ]]; then
echo "$USERID have Quota limit = 1"
else
echo "$USERID have no Quota Limitations = 0 , So removing it from the users list."
sed -i '/\$USERID\>/d' /tmp/username.txt
fi
done
```

`sed -i '/\$USERID\>/d' /tmp/username.txt` >> This command in bash is not removing the exact matched username. I want to delete line which contains specific username (variable).

**Second Query:**

File contains following lines

```
cOke is bad 
diet-COKE 
cokeisgood
```

How can i cat this file and search for any word which contains "**coke**" in it regardless of lower or upper case.

Answer (score 1):

> sed -i '/\$USERID>/d' /tmp/username.txt

You have enclosed your sed expression in `'` single quotes. This will stop the expansion of $USERID and cause it to be used as a string literal. You should enclose the sed expression in `"` double quotes to allow the variable expansion.

> File contains following lines

The `-i` switch to grep ignores case.

You can also use I (capital i) in a sed expression for (this may be a GNU sed thing)

```
echo "cOke is bad" | sed -n "/coke/Ip"
```